Mark a data validation dropdown criteria as done, if a certain value is in another cell?
I have a work sheet, and I am using data validation dropdown options to track the progress of the workflow. I have a certain section of that workflow that is only needed when the job is for a specific project. The data validation options are "Done" "In progress" and "Not started". Is there a way to make it so that when, say for example, cell E 26 has the value of "FALSE", the data validation dropdown options in the cells E10:E14 are automatically set as Done.
Example sheet will show how I have it set right now, and the "Result" sheet will show what I would like it to look like:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y_mbGtw4uDbCi0qWSfpmlwnhJ-Zo706bmetswj694gc/edit?usp=sharing
I tried using custom formulas, but they overwrite the dropdown options.

This question is similar to: Multiple dependent dynamic dropdowns with repeating column dropdowns in Google Sheets. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is a known question. The search term you are looking for is a Dynamic Dropdown.
